# How do I make a 2D array initialization function with pointers?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function that takes in the pointer of the 2d array and the integers y and x based on the size of the array. I keep getting errors here and was hoping someone could help me out. the function randNum just returns a random integer from 0 to 9.

```
void initialize(int t[], int y, int x){
  for(p = &t[0][0]; p <= &t[y-1][x-1]; p++){
    *(t + ((y*x) + x)) = randomNum(0,9);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use p inside the loop?

Comment: Also, I am not sure about this, but shouldn't t[] be a pointer where the Compiler expects only one dimension to be? It would know that t[i] = *(t + i * sizeof(int)), but afaik it would not know how to evaluate t[y-1][x-1] because here we have an array inside an array. The compiler would need to know the size of the inner arrays as "sizeof", but it cannot know this value.

Comment: I was following Neso Academy (a youtube channel)'s 2d array print video. I was hoping to use his concept to make an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void initialize(int t[], int y, int x){
  for(int *i = t, i < t + x * y; i++)
    *i = randomNum(0,9);
}
```

Explanation:
Your array contains x times y integers, so it is a memory segment containing those. Thus, we can see it as an one dimensional array of size x*y.

Your code does not work because for instance the compiler would have no way to determine what

```
&t[y-1][x-1]
```

even is. For an integer array a the compiler would know that for

```
*(a + k) == a[k]
```

it would need to take the address of a and add k times the size of an integer (usually 4 bytes). For

```
a[k][l]
```

we would need to take

```
*(a + innerdimension * k + l)
```

but as the compiler does not know what the inner dimension is it cannot work.

Alternatively you could also go for something like

```
void intitialize(int *t, int y, int x){
  for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
      *(t + i * x + j) = randomNum(0,9);
}
```

While this is a bit longer it would exactly describe how you would iterate over an 2D array while replacing the not working t[i][j] by its equivalent *(t + i*x + j) given a known inner dimension x.

Comment: While your answer should work on paper I got a lot of errors as shown below. Any idea?

main.c: In function ‘intitialize’:
main.c:14:3: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘for’

Comment: Could you please elaborate which of the two functions is failing where? What Do you mean by "lot of errors", are there more?

Comment: fixed, got a missing "{"

Comment: Yeah that was it